# Argo CD pods and namespace stuck on terminating when uninstalling Helm chart with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I'm installing Argo CD using its helm chart through Terraform definition like below. The setup is simple, I create a namespace separate so it can be deleted on `terraform destroy` then I install the chart.

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "ns_argocd" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "argocd"
    }

    name = "argocd"
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "argocd" {
  name             = "argocd"
  repository       = "https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm"
  chart            = "argo-cd"
  namespace        = kubernetes_namespace.ns_argocd.metadata.0.name
  create_namespace = false

  version    = "5.13.1"

  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.ns_argocd]
}
```

Since I am still experimenting on the setup, I have to destroy and recreate a few times and every time that I hit `terraform destroy` it times out because the pods and the namespace are stuck on `terminating` status (see below). My current fix is to manually force delete every pod and namespace via `kubectl delete [pod] -n argocd --force`.

Is there anything that I'm missing to pass to the values file that will prevent this behavior?

```bash
NAME              STATUS        AGE
argocd            Terminating   3h58m
default           Active        4h4m
kube-node-lease   Active        4h4m
kube-public       Active        4h4m
kube-system       Active        4h4m
```

```bash
NAME                                                READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
argocd-application-controller-0                     1/1     Terminating   0          3h55m
argocd-applicationset-controller-7bb6d6d68c-p52j7   1/1     Terminating   0          3h55m
argocd-dex-server-6bc5f5689c-ps6wk                  1/1     Terminating   0          3h55m
argocd-notifications-controller-57bd8dbc87-msdnw    1/1     Terminating   0          3h55m
argocd-redis-77df65946d-fhb46                       1/1     Terminating   0          3h55m
argocd-repo-server-6984b7475d-b2625                 1/1     Terminating   0          3h55m
argocd-server-548dffcdcc-nbrhc                      1/1     Terminating   0          3h55m
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the explicit dependency created with `depends_on`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried doing a destroy for both at the same time and separate as well

Comment: Have you done some research why they are in terminating state, e.g, checking the logs?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link. It highlights the issue with orphaned CRDs left by Terraform. We also need to set the finalizers to [].

https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints/issues/865